# Can't run swift project on Iphone with Skobbler

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, ios8, osx-yosemite

**I have this error when I build the project on Iphone :**

> Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)!
>   /Users/Tom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-bwacbfyhutgdvnhetuiouvtcvvfi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Test.app/Frameworks/SKMaps.framework: invalid resource specification rule(s)
>   Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

If I built the project with the iOS Simulator, it run perfectly

*I Work with swift 1.2 - Xcode 6.3.1 and OSX 10.10.3*

Thank you for your help !

Ysee

**EDIT : 
I solved this problem, I had to manually install Skobbler SDK then I tested the installation with cocoapods. This works perfectly!**

Comment: You should write the solution as answer and accept your own answer.

Comment: Well, that's done. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem, I had to manually install Skobbler SDK then I tested the installation with cocoapods. This works perfectly!
If you work with Swift don't forget to add #import "SKMaps/SKMaps.h" in your Bridging-Header.h

Ysee